# WAV file audio sync/distortion issue

Tags: distortion, waveform-similarity

I was using Scarlet 2i2 audio interface plugged into an Android phone. Monitor headphones on the interface sounded great! I recorded a WAV file of a kids' concert with the USB Audio Recorder Pro app, which is designed to get audio from AIs via USB.

I've done this before and everything worked great. This time something went wonky! I know for a fact that I set the app to read/record at 48000/24-bit, but now my file says 44100 and sounds terrible and has a ton of random light crackle/distortion, rendering the recording unusable. The pitch sounds a bit off.

I tried to manually change the bitrate in the file to 48000 inside the file and I tried to convert and interpret the file at different bitrates in Audition. It just changes the pitch but no improvement of distortion. I tried click/crackle remover plugins, creative editing to smooth it out with saturation and EQ, but it's too much damage to cover up. I'm not sure if the issue is with the WAV file and how it was written and the audio is fully there, or if it's actually a 44100 file missing some of the 48000 data, so the damage is permanent. I really hope it's not, and a decent audio can be extracted.

I have an external mic recording which sounds really reverberated, but I was planning to use it as “room reverb” at a much lower level to smooth out the main file. Maybe I can do something with both files to cover the issues in the main one? Problem at this point is that I can't even get the files to match. When I try to resize the bad file to match the good one in Audition, I can't get them to match up in signal peaks, as if there was some slippage or sync issue in the bad file that it's not even recorded at a constant rate, but maybe that's user error. Any ideas you come up with would be SO VERY WELCOME! I'm pretty decent at writing code, so if you can come up with a theoretical idea, maybe I can implement it.

I've also noticed that the waveform has a rather strange periodic wave overlapping the rest of the frequency. Not all the time, but with a periodic amplitude as well. [Here's a screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mf464cb6670q2c7/sample_broken_waveform.jpg?dl=0) at one of the higher peaks. Fairly difficult to capture/time it just right.

Examples are below:

[Sample of broken audio from audio interface](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o6meenap0osgr5a/sample_broken.mp3?dl=0)

[Sample of audio from external mic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pca38npp5tyatkw/sample_ext_microphone.mp3?dl=0)

I'm desperate to restore this recording. I'd be so infinitely grateful for all constructive ideas and advice!

Comment: Do you still have the uncompressed originals, or just these mp3 files?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have uncompressed originals and I can code, but I'm not very well versed on working with WAV data. Something I'll have to learn if you have a solution for me.

Comment: Here's the original. It's 1.5Gb. Pretty damn huge, so it will take a bit of time to download. It's actually still uploading. If you cannot open it in the next few minutes, try in half-an-hour: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3c61669nsatw4p0/Record_2022_12_04_160849.151_original.wav?dl=0

Comment: downloaded it, don't have time to play with it right now, but it might look like a strange sample data drop. hm.

Comment: Clock out of sync? Packets dropped to catch up?

Comment: This is cross-posted, so I'm closing it on Sound Design.